# Getting blank screen in avVideo player while entering to foreground in uitableviewCell

Tags: swift, video-streaming, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

I am using AVPlayer for a custom video player and getting a blank screen while I enter from the background.

```
func playSingleVideo(pauseAll: Bool = false,foreground:Bool = false) {
    if let visibleCells = self.tableView.visibleCells as? [VideoCell], !visibleCells.isEmpty {
        if pauseAll {
            visibleCells.forEach { $0.playerLayer?.player?.pause() }
        } else {
            var maxHeightRequired: Int = 50
            var cellToPlay: VideoCell?
            
            visibleCells.reversed().forEach { (cell) in
                let cellBounds = self.view.convert(cell.videoView.frame, from: cell.videoView)
                let visibleCellHeight = Int(self.view.frame.intersection(cellBounds).height)
                
                if visibleCellHeight >= maxHeightRequired {
                    maxHeightRequired = visibleCellHeight
                    cellToPlay = cell
                }
            }
            
            visibleCells.forEach { (cell) in
                
                
                if cell === cellToPlay {
                    
                    cell.slider.minimumValue = 0.0

                    cell.playerLayer?.player?.play()
                    cell.btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause-button") , for: .normal)
                    cell.btnPlay.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

//                        cell.videoView.layer.insertSublayer(cell.playerLayer!, at: 0)

```
                } else {
                    cell.playerLayer?.player?.pause()
                    cell.btnPlay.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

//                        cell.videoView.layer.insertSublayer(cell.playerLayer!, at: 0)
cell.slider.minimumValue = 0.0
cell.btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button") , for: .normal)

```
                }
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: cell.playerLayer?.player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
                    cell.playerLayer?.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                    cell.playerLayer?.player?.play()
                }
                
                let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
                cell.playerLayer?.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in
                    
                    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
                    let secondString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) % 60)
                    let minutString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) / 60)
                    print( "\(minutString):\(secondString)")
                    cell.lblElapsed.text = "\(minutString):\(secondString)"
                    cell.playerLayer?.player?.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(exactly: 100)!
                    cell.videoView.layer.insertSublayer(cell.playerLayer!, at: 0)
                    
                    guard let duration = cell.playerLayer?.player?.currentItem?.duration else { return  }
                    
                    
                    let seconds2 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                    if !seconds2.isNaN{
                        let sec = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds2)  % 60)
                        let min = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds2)  / 60)
                        print("\(min):\(sec)")
                        cell.lblTotal.text = "\(min):\(sec)"
                        let totsec = seconds / seconds2
                        
                        if !self.isended{
                            cell.slider.setValue(Float(totsec), animated: true)
                            
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This info is so very little. Please provide a code snippet and explain more of your problem.

Comment: Please check the above snippet. @PankajGaikar I calling the above function while entering in the foreground.

Comment: The code looks super complicated but it seems you are losing AVPlayerLayer in process when coming to foreground. You need to maintain or use same AVPlayerLayer instance that was playing and set on view while app went to background.